# WordPress ACFNotice: get_field() - We've detected one or more calls to retrieve ACF field values before ACF has been initialized

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress website has this notice below, how do I fix this?

*Notice: acf_get_value was called **incorrectly**. **Advanced Custom Fields PRO** - We've detected one or more calls to retrieve ACF field values before ACF has been initialized. This is not supported and can result in malformed or missing data. Learn how to fix this. Please see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message was added in version 5.11.1.) in*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new version for ACF Pro now requires the initialization as below

```
add_action( 'acf/init', 'custom_code' );

function custom_code() {
    acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'group_1',
        'title' => 'Page Hero',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_1',
                'label' => 'Hero Title',
                'name' => hero_title,
                'type' => 'text',
            )
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => page,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

You can wrap your existing `acf_add_local_field_group()`s or `acf_add_local_field()` in a function and then use add_action to initialise it as shown - `add_action( 'acf/init', 'custom_code' )`;